# Calculate the vertex while creating terrain from heightmap using ThreeJs

Tags: three.js

I'm reading "create terrain from heightmap" example from ThreeJs Cookbook

This example load GrandCanyon:  http://lh5.ggpht.com/_-B0hFoGrn-w/SvHiYk39yAI/AAAAAAAABOQ/6IGZwifUYGA/GrandCanyon.png

And create a 3D terrain: http://www.smartjava.org/tjscb/02-geometries-meshes/02.06-create-terrain-from-heightmap.html

There are some code pieces I can not understand:

```
// draw on canvas
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var pixel = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, width, depth);

        var geom = new THREE.Geometry;
        var output = [];
        for (var x = 0; x < depth; x++) {
            for (var z = 0; z < width; z++) {
                // get pixel
                // since we're grayscale, we only need one element

                var yValue = pixel.data[z * 4 + (depth * x * 4)] / heightOffset;                       
                var vertex = new THREE.Vector3(x * spacingX, yValue, z * spacingZ);
                geom.vertices.push(vertex);
            }
        }
```

why is yValue calculated with that value ? why don't we use var yValue = pixel.data[z * 4 + (depth * x )] or something like that ?

And do we really need spacingX and spacingZ ?

Source code is here: https://github.com/josdirksen/threejs-cookbook/blob/master/02-geometries-meshes/02.06-create-terrain-from-heightmap.html

Could you please help me ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't NEED spacingX and spacingZ, no. You could adjust scale in other ways, like applying a scale matrix to the entire THREE.Geometry after you've populated the vertices. Up to you, really.

As fort the yValue, the indexing is to adjust for the way the data for the texture is laid out. There are four channels, usually RGBA, but in this case we only need one of them as a height.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand why do we need to calculate yValue like that. z*4 = I can understand that we get A value but why do we need (depth * x * 4) ? If I use depth*x or other depth*x*other_value the terrain will be ugly

Comment: that is correct, the original author jsut chose "4" as an arbitrary constant. Other scales are perfectly valid.